# Optimization and speedup of a mathematical function in python

Tags: python, numpy, cython, pyopencl, numexpr

The purpose of this mathematical function is to compute a distance between two (or more) protein structures using dihedral angles:

[image]

It is very useful in structural biology, for example. And I already code this function in python using numpy, but the goal is to have a faster implementation. As computation time reference, I use the euclidean distance function available in the scikit-learn package.

Here the code I have for the moment:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

# We have 10000 structures with 100 dihedral angles
n = 10000
m = 100

# Generate some random data
c = np.random.rand(n,m)
# Generate random int number
x = np.random.randint(c.shape[0])

print c.shape, x

# First version with numpy of the dihedral_distances function
def dihedral_distances(a, b):
    l = 1./a.shape[0]
    return np.sqrt(l* np.sum((0.5)*(1. - np.cos(a-b)), axis=1))

# Accelerated version with numexpr
def dihedral_distances_ne(a, b):
    l = 1./a.shape[0]
    tmp = ne.evaluate('sum((0.5)*(1. - cos(a-b)), axis=1)')
    return ne.evaluate('sqrt(l* tmp)')

# The function of reference I try to be close as possible 
# in term of computation time
%timeit euclidean_distances(c[x,:], c)[0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop

# Computation time of the first version of the dihedral_distances function
# We choose randomly 1 structure among the 10000 structures.
# And we compute the dihedral distance between this one and the others
%timeit dihedral_distances(c[x,:], c)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.5 ms per loop

# Computation time of the accelerated function with numexpr
%timeit dihedral_distances_ne(c[x,:], c)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.44 ms per loop
```

9.44 ms it's very fast, but it's very slow if you need to run it a million times. Now the question is, how to do that? What is the next step? Cython? PyOpenCL? I have some experience with PyOpenCL, however I never code something as elaborate as this one. I don't know if it's possible to compute the dihedral distances in one step on GPU as I do with numpy and how to proceed.

Thank you for helping me!

EDIT:
Thank you guys! I am currently working on the full solution and once it's finished I will put the code here.

CYTHON VERSION:

```
%load_ext cython
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

n = 10000
m = 100

c = np.random.rand(n,m)
x = np.random.randint(c.shape[0])

print c.shape, x

%%cython --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp --force

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sqrt, cos
cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport parallel, prange

# Define a function pointer to a metric
ctypedef double (*metric)(double[: ,::1], np.intp_t, np.intp_t)

cdef extern from "math.h" nogil:
    double cos(double x)
    double sqrt(double x)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double dihedral_distances(double[:, ::1] a, np.intp_t i1, np.intp_t i2):
    cdef double res
    cdef int m
    cdef int j

    res = 0.
    m = a.shape[1]

    for j in range(m):
        res += 1. - cos(a[i1, j] - a[i2, j])

    res /= 2.*m

    return sqrt(res)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double dihedral_distances_p(double[:, ::1] a, np.intp_t i1, np.intp_t i2):
    cdef double res
    cdef int m
    cdef int j

    res = 0.
    m = a.shape[1]

    with nogil, parallel(num_threads=2):
        for j in prange(m, schedule='dynamic'):
            res += 1. - cos(a[i1, j] - a[i2, j])

    res /= 2.*m

    return sqrt(res)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def pairwise(double[: ,::1] c not None, np.intp_t x, p = True):
    cdef metric dist_func
    if p:
        dist_func = &dihedral_distances_p
    else:
        dist_func = &dihedral_distances

    cdef np.intp_t i, n_structures
    n_samples = c.shape[0]

    cdef double[::1] res = np.empty(n_samples)

    for i in range(n_samples):
        res[i] = dist_func(c, x, i)

    return res

%timeit pairwise(c, x, False)
100 loops, best of 3: 17 ms per loop    

# Parallel version
%timeit pairwise(c, x, True)
10 loops, best of 3: 37.1 ms per loop
```

So I follow your [link](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/) to create the cython version of the dihedral distances function. We gain some speed, not so much, but it is still slower than the numexpr version (17ms vs 9.44ms). So I tried to parallelize the function using prange and it is worse (37.1ms vs 17ms vs 9.4ms)!

Do I miss something?

Comment: A couple of small improvements are: 1) put the `*0.5` outside of the sum; and, 2) sum the `cos` before subtracting the from `1` (which will be more accurate as well, since the sum will hang around 1).  For me these bring it from 25ms to 17ms.  I know you're looking for more, but this is what I got and thought it might help a bit.

Comment: Trying out cython is easy and can give quite a speedup (YMMV, of course): https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/

Comment: @tom10 Effectively with 1) I gain more than 1ms but 2) give me an error `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt`.

Comment: For 2, if you sum over N items then `sqrt(sum(1 - cos(x)))` becomes `sqrt(N - sum(cos(x)))`.  Did you remember the N?

Comment: @tom10 Yeah, you're right! I hadn't seen the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to use http://pythran.readthedocs.io/, you can leverage on the numpy implementation and get better performance than cython for that case:

```
#pythran export np_cos_norm(float[], float[])
import numpy as np
def np_cos_norm(a, b):
    val = np.sum(1. - np.cos(a-b))
    return np.sqrt(val / 2. / a.shape[0])
```

And compile it with:

```
pythran fast.py
```

To get an average x2 over the cython version.

If using:

```
pythran fast.py -march=native -DUSE_BOOST_SIMD -fopenmp
```

You'll get a vectorized, parallel version that runs slightly faster:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.54 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 674 ns per loop

100000 loops, best of 3: 16.9 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.31 µs per loop

10000 loops, best of 3: 176 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.9 µs per loop
```

(using the same testbed as ev-br)

Comment: Cocorico! \o/ It seems very promising but not so easy too use [(pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/W403EsXQ). Apparently I have a problem with the boost library or something else. It doesn't compile. Other detail I didn't mention in the pastebin, I am running under OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: @NoExiT: What if you add -DNDEBUG to the compile flags, as in pythran -DNDEBUG fast.py ?

Comment: What if you force g++-4.9 as a compiler?

Comment: We are close to the end! 1) So I installed g++-4.9 using homebrew and this [link](http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Max/Building_a_GCC_4.9_cross_compiler_on_OS_X_Mavericks), then 2) I modify .pythranrc with `cxx = g++-4.9` and finally when I ran it again I only had one error `ld: library not found for -lboost_python-mt`. I put the complete report [here](http://pastebin.com/fhxnAvwQ).

Comment: Update: I didn't install boost-python ... So I `brew install boost-python`. Then I had this error `ld: library not found for -ltcmalloc_minimal`. So I updated the .pythranrc file to `ldflags = -fPIC` only. And now it's working! \o/ [(installation summary)](http://pastebin.com/1xjaXnZC)

Comment: you forgot the -DNDEBUG again :-)

Comment: Yes, I did it on purpose to try if it works without ... and the answer is no. Whatever, when I do `pythran -DNDEBUG fast.py; python -c 'import fast'` I obtain a segmentation fault `Segmentation fault: 11`. So, there is still have a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88289/discussion-between-serge-sans-paille-and-noexit).

Comment: @serge-sans-paille: can you provide an explanation of how pythran might provide a speed improvement?  For this simple equation, there's very little looping and almost all of the time will be spent in numpy's compiled C code.  That is, in the absence of Python loops, I don't see why compiling python code will give a speed improvement over per-compiled numpy code.  Is it just a better compiler?

Comment: @tom10: numpy creates a temporary array for each operation. So to compute `np.sum(1. - np.cos(a-b))`  it uses 3 temporary (and useless) arrays. Pythran fuses the loops, which also makes vectorization and parallelization more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick-and-dirty try with cython, for just a pair of 1D arrays:

(in an IPython notebook)

```
%%cython

cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double cos(double x) nogil
    double sqrt(double x) nogil

def cos_norm(a, b):
    return cos_norm_impl(a, b)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double cos_norm_impl(double[::1] a, double[::1] b) nogil:
    cdef double res = 0., val
    cdef int m = a.shape[0]
    # XXX: shape of b not checked
    cdef int j

    for j in range(m):
        val = a[j] - b[j]
        res += 1. - cos(val)
    res /= 2.*m

    return sqrt(res)
```

Comparing with a straightforward numpy implementation,

```
def np_cos_norm(a, b):
    val = np.add.reduce(1. - np.cos(a-b))
    return np.sqrt(val / 2. / a.shape[0])
```

I get

```
np.random.seed(1234)

for n in [100, 1000, 10000]:
    x = np.random.random(n)
    y = np.random.random(n)
    %timeit cos_norm(x, y)
    %timeit np_cos_norm(x, y)
    print '\n'

100000 loops, best of 3: 3.04 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

100000 loops, best of 3: 18.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.8 µs per loop

1000 loops, best of 3: 196 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 223 µs per loop
```

So, depending on the dimensionality of your vectors, you can get from a factor of 4 to nil of a speedup.

For computing pairwise distances, you can probably do much better, as shown in [this blog post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/), but of course YMMV.

Comment: Thank you @ev-br! I am working on it. There is just a little error in the `np_cos_norm` function, it's `val = np.add.reduce(1. - np.cos(a-b), axis=1)`.

Comment: This is deliberate: I only handle 1D arrays here.